# Error while using atoi

Tags: c

I am reading the input from stdin using fgets and then saving the integer values using atoi.

input:
1 2 3 4

```
int main()
{
    char line[100];
    char *token;
    int row,column[10];
    const char split[2] = " ";

    fgets(line,100,stdin);
    token=strtok(line,split);
    row = atoi(token); //not getting any error
    while( token != NULL )
    {
        token=strtok(NULL,split);
      //  printf("column %d",atoi(token)); //getting an exception
       // column[0]= atoi(token);//error
    }
}
```

Output:

> a.exe
>
> 1 2

```
>  1 [main] a 16776 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to a.exe.stackdump
```

Comment: What do you mean by "error"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `token` in the wrong order to extract the values.

When you use:

```
while( token != NULL )
{
   token=strtok(NULL,split);
   // What happens you reach the end of the tokens and 
   // token is NULL? You are still using it in atoi.
   printf("column %d",atoi(token));
   column[0]= atoi(token);
}
```

You need to use:

```
while( token != NULL )
{
   printf("column %d",atoi(token));
   column[0]= atoi(token);
   token=strtok(NULL,split);
}
```

Comment: `column[i++] = atoi(token)` else we will always be overwriting the same element